# Property files conflict in spring

Tags: spring, properties, placeholder

I have the following problem

In common.xml I have included property file via

```
<context:property location  ="classpath:x.properties" />
```

In custom.xml I have imported common.xml and included another property file

```
<context:property location ="classpath:y.properties" />
```

When I try to use property placeholder from y.properties file  for ex. ${my.name} I get an error that Spring could not recognize "my.name"

I can't use both property files in same xml, I can't use multiple locations

I wonder if anyone have ever used properties file in different xml files. Is this possible? Why there is a conflict, when we use 2 or more properties files?

Answer (score 1):

Use one context:property-placheolder element and specify multiple values for the location attribute for example

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:x.properties,classpath:y.properties"/>
```

In your case one element is overriding the other

Comment: So it means I 'm not able to use two context placeholders?

Comment: In your scenario its creating two bean factory post processors. The first will try to resolve all ${} but will not find placeholders in the other file and throw an exception. To allow each file to partially replace add the attribute ignore-unresolvable="true" to each context:property-placeholder element

Comment: When first bean factory post processor will not find placeholder (if ignore unresolved is true), then second factory will try to find it?